# How to pass a date from a static site form to a Google Form?

Tags: forms, date, google-sheets, integration, google-forms

I have a simple form on an HTML site. The form is integrated with Google Form and then on with Google Sheets. To give you more details: when a user submits a form on my website the data is passed to fill the Google Form and then are saved in the Google Spreadsheet.

The problem I have is **passing a date field.** How should I pass a date field to a Google Form?
With a text field there is no problem as I match them by using for example `name="entry.77808571"`
BUT,
for a date Google Form has three entries, e.g.:
`name="entry.1307321649_year" name="entry.1307321649_month" name="entry.1307321649_day"`

So 3 "name" properties for one input field.

I provide my code for the form, so hopefully you can see what I mean above:

```
<form  action="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSfglf8uoaPBwXQNZb44C3qyDfxV7mv4wIlSTamUfHwolsJ0Lg/formResponse">
                 
          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
              <label class="control-label" for="date">Date</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="entry.1307321649" placeholder="Zameldowanie" id="date" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter dates." autocomplete="off">
              <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
              <label class="control-label" for="date">Date</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="entry.77808571" placeholder="Wymeldowanie" id="date" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter dates." autocomplete="off">
              <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
          </div>  
          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
              <label>Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Imię i Nazwisko" id="name" name="entry.191476008" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
              <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
              <label>Email Address</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Adres Email" id="email" name="entry.1612291661" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
              <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
              <label>Phone Number</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Numer Telefonu" id="phone" name="entry.199915649" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
              <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
              <label>Message</label>
              <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Wiadomość" id="message" name="entry.948216718" data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
              <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div id="success"></div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="sendMessage">Rezerwuj</button>
        </form>
```

So far I used a workaround and passed the date as a text. But then I'm having a problem with integrating it with Google Calendar (the data goes from Google Sheets to Calendar), as I need to have a date not text to do so.

Please shout if you have any questions and counting for your help.
Many thanks!
Justyna

Comment: Once you submit the data, how are you trying to integrate it into the calendar?

Comment: The integration to calendar is from sheets usings add-on. It's not the mian point here. My problem is how to pass a date format into Google Forms. When this is done, everything else will work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can pass a date that will be reconized as such correctly as following:

Just pass the full netry for the date, without separating into year, month and day - just as you are doing now. So:

```
<div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
  <label class="control-label" for="date">Date</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="entry.1307321649" placeholder="Zameldowanie" id="date" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter dates." autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

**When filling out your custom HTML form, paste the full date into the corresponding input field in the format `2020-10-15`.**

In this format your date will be recognized in the destination spreadsheet correctly as a date object.

Btw, if you create a Prefill URL for your Google form, it will look  e.g. like following:
`https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/XXX/viewform?entry.1141768477=Option+1&entry.1199891753=mail@mail.com&entry.1037962790=2020-10-20&entry.2138552921=Option+1`

This allows you to see the correct formatting for dates, multiple-choice options etc.

Comment: This does not work, as in the excel it is not treated as a date object but as text. The sheet adds " ' " before the date like this " '16-10-2020 ". This is perhabs because in the Google Form in order to pass the full entry I must have the text input NOT date. If I change the Google Form input into a date there is an error when submitting a form.

Comment: I just tested it myself and it works for me. Maybe it depends on the country settibga of your Google sheet? (Locale)? I assume we are both talking about Google Sheets, not Excel?

Comment: In Google Forms did you set the date field as date or text?

Comment: In Google Forms I set it as Date.

Comment: You were right. If I change the date format to yyyy-mm-dd it works. The problem is in my country the date format we use is dd-mm-yyyy. Have you any idea how to force Google Forms to accept local date format?

Comment: Not sure if this is possible, but maybe you can implement the format conversion programmatically?

Comment: OK, thanks anyway for your help, it is much appreciated. At least I got it working. The format issue is not burning at the moment, I may tackle it later on. Cheers! :)